# XNA Point Counter

Tags: c#, xna, counter, points

I am making a game where a player runs around collecting Kiwis. I want the point counter to increment by only one each time. What I have so far is that the pointer increments, but keeps incrementing. i.e. when the player touches a kiwi the counter keeps on increasing by 1.

Here is the Intersect method:

```
public void Intersect(Rectangle playerRect, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (Rectangle kiwiRect in kiwiRectangle.Except(collectedKiwis))
        {
            if (kiwiRect.Intersects(playerRect))
            {
                collectedKiwis.Add(kiwiRect);
                isCollected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(kiwiTexture, kiwiRect, Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here are the Update and Draw methods:

```
public void Update()
    {
        points = "Points: " + counter;
        if (isCollected)
        {
            counter++;
        }

    }

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(pointCounter, points, new Vector2(500, 10), Color.Red);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should check for 2 conditions at least:

- If player is currently intersected with kiwi
- If that kiwi hasn't already been collected (isCollected prop i suppose)

So if you are intersected and kiwi isn't yet collected, you set isCollected flag and increase counter. On the next Update() run you will skip that kiwi (if you haven't deleted it yet or want to perform some animation) as you've already set isCollected flag, like:

```
if (Intersect(...) && !isCollected)
    {
        counter++;
        isCollected=true;
    }
```

Though this approach answers your question, i advice you to think about the whole game logic you will want to implement, for ex. how are all of the kiwis will be managed and how to check only active kiwis for intersection to improve performance :)